# AttributeError at /edit-menu/edit/ 'Product' object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to pull all of the product names from the Product model, display them and their prices on the screen, and then be able to change the product price of any of these items. I have it so it lists them out and has an input field for the price, but get this error when I submit. 
AttributeError at /edit-menu/edit/ 'Product' object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Please help.

views.py:

```
def edit_menu(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { "object_list": queryset }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post=Product()
        if request.POST.get('price'):
            if post.is_valid():
                post.price= request.POST.get('price')
                post.save()

                return redirect('mis446/edit-menu.html', context)
            else: 
                return redirect(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
    else:

        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
```

Models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

html:

```
<div class = "container">
    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}

         {% for instance in object_list %}
{{ instance.name}}: <input type="number" name="price" value = '{{ instance.price }}'/><br>

    {% endfor %}
<button type ="submit">Submit Changes</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is my urls.py for this and my normal edit menu page where users add menu items

```
path('edit-menu/', views.add_to_menu, name='Edit Menu'),

url(r'^edit-menu/edit/$',views.edit_menu, name='Edit Menu Item'),
```

Now I am getting this error: 
NoReverseMatch at /edit-menu/edit/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

New views.py:

```
def edit_menu(request):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { "object_list": queryset }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post=ProductModelForm(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('price'):
            if post.is_valid():
                post.save()

                return redirect('Edit Menu', context)
            else: 
                return redirect('Edit Menu', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
    else:

        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
```

and now I get this error: 
NoReverseMatch at /edit-menu/edit/
Reverse for 'Edit Menu' with arguments '({'object_list': , , , , , , , ]>},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit\-menu/$']

That list is the list of products.

Newest edit:

Now it is accepting values, but instead of updating the price form something in the database, it is just putting a price in the price column with no name or slug. It is essentially just adding rathe than replacing data.

forms.py:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price']
```

Views.py:

```
def edit_menu(request):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { "object_list": queryset }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post=ProductModelForm(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('price'):
            if post.is_valid():

                post.save()

                return redirect('Edit Menu Item')
            else: 
                return redirect('Edit Menu Item')
        else:
            return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
    else:

        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
 <select>
         {% for instance in object_list %}

<option name = "name">{{ instance.name}}: ${{ instance.price }}</option>

    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="price" value = '{{ instance.price }}'/><br>
<button type ="submit">Submit Changes</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The product is a models.Model instance and it doesn't have an is_valid method, you should first write a form

create a file in your app directory named forms.py, in forms.py first import ModelForm and your Product model

```py
     from django import forms
     from .models import Product
```

then create appropriate associated form class with your Product model like below

```py
    class ProductModelFrom(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ['name', 'price'] # specify which field you need to be in the form
            # I didn't write the slug field there because you probably don't want the user to enter the slug.
            # the better way is to manage slugs in models.py and prepopulate it from the name
```

then in the views.py import your form

```py
from .forms import ProductModelForm

def edit_menu(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { "object_list": queryset }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post=ProductModelFrom(request.POST) # initialize form with data entered in front-end
        if request.POST.get('price'):
            if post.is_valid():
                # post.price= request.POST.get('price') Remove this line too
                # because when we initialize the form, it would contains price and name entered by the user
                post.save()

                return redirect('mis446/edit-menu.html', context)
            else: 
                return redirect('mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context) # redirect does not need the request
        else:
            return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
    else:

        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
```

Comment: Hey Dawood! Thank you for your help. I did what you said, and now I am getting a new error. I updated my post and at the bottom it shows the error. Thank you for your quick replies.

Comment: hi, normally reverse not found occurs when django can't resolve the URL correctly, and it's a common error, definitely, if you search on google the exact error, you will find some useful StackOverflow topics

Comment: one more error exists in your code 
return redirect(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
you should not pass the request to redirect, it will just get URL name and context

Comment: I updated it again with a new error I am receiving. I apologize for all the assistance I am needing. This is my first web app and first time using Django.

Comment: congratulations on your first app, but really you should try Google-ing more,

[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) in the documentation says for editing data you should provide an initial data for your forms, so in the view first, fetch model instance you want to edit, then pass it to modelForm instance as initial

`target_instance = Product.objects.get(id=id_of_instance_to_be_edited)`
 and then  
`post=ProductModelFrom(request.POST, initial=target_instance)`

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py`

The `class Product(models.Model):` doesn't have a `is_valid=models.BooleanField(default=True)` field.

In `urls.py`

You just can't write like this

```
path('edit-menu/', views.add_to_menu, name='Edit Menu'),

url(r'^edit-menu/edit/$',views.edit_menu, name='Edit Menu Item'),
```

Rather it should be like this

```
path('edit-menu/', views.add_to_menu, name='edit-menu'),

url(r'^edit-menu/edit/$',views.edit_menu, name='edit-menu-item'),
```

So now in your `views.py`

you will write the return redirect as

```
  return redirect('edit-menu', context)
            else: 
                return redirect('edit-menu', context)
```